# Where to get consumer secret required by buzz-python-client?

Tags: python, google-buzz

I am using [buzz-python-client](http://code.google.com/p/buzz-python-client/) and there is the following line in the examples:

```
client.build_oauth_consumer('your-app.appspot.com', 'consumer_secret')
```

Where can I get a `'consumer_secret'`?

Answer (score 6):

as [docs explain](http://buzz-python-client.googlecode.com/hg/docs/buzz.Client-class.html#build_oauth_consumer):

> `secret` (string) - Your consumer secret. This is issued to you by Google.

[Official guide to registration with Google](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/RegistrationForWebAppsAuto.html).